# (Circular motion)Time Speed and Distance.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

A,B and C start running on a circular track from the same point.
A and B run in a clockwise fashion.
C runs anti clockwise.
When A and C meet for the first time,
C is at a distance which is equal to quarter of  circumference of circular track.
It is also known that A runs faster than C.
The ratio of speeds of A,C and B cannot be.

$\large \color{black}{  a.)\quad 5:1:2 \quad \hspace{.33em}\\~\\
b.)\quad 3:1:1 \quad\hspace{.33em}\\~\\
c.)\quad 4:2:1 \quad \hspace{.33em}\\~\\
d.)\quad 3:2:1 \quad \hspace{.33em}\\~\\
}$

options are showing ratio of speeds of $A:C:B$.

so far from the question i have drawn the two possible diagrams .
where B's speed can be $\text{
speed_{B}}>\text{
speed_{A}}$ or
$\text{
speed_{A}}>\text{
speed_{B}}$.

and concluded that$ \text{
speed_{A}}:\text{
speed_{C}}::3:1$

[image]

[image]

screenshot of the question

[image]

Comment: Where's this problem from?

Comment: This is the [source](http://http://www.mheducation.co.in/9789339205126-india-how-to-prepare-for-quantitative-aptitude-for-cat) of the problem.

Comment: what is the role of $B?$

Comment: With the source of the problem it says: "This page can’t be displayed".

Comment: [source](http://www.mheducation.co.in/9789339205126-india-how-to-prepare-for-quantitative-aptitude-for-cat)

Comment: @RK: What exactly do you and the OP ask for? The OP has already indicated the correct solution above, solution (b).

Comment: @RK: The first link that you give misses the ":" after "http". The second redirects me at the .uk domain of a commercial entity. How difficult is it to correctly post a web address in 2015?

Comment: @AlexM.:the first source was broken but the second link i posted works fine for me(at least in my country), any ways i have added a screenshot of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the ratio of speeds of A and C is $3:1$  That shows that none of a,c,d are correct.  b is still a possibility.  Any of a,c,d should be an acceptable answer.  I suspect it is a typo and instead of "cannot" it should be "might", when b would be the correct answer.  My logic is just trying to find a simple rewording that yields a single correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think one can answer this MC question correctly. Assuming that this question is solvable, we can say that it has a unique solution (which should appear as one of the options) and this will leave the remaining three options become “cannot be’s”. This question is then equivalent to requiring to choose a “cannot be” from three “cannot be’s”. How?

---

However, I found this question has the following tricky part:-

“When A and C **meet** for the first time, C is **at a distance which is equal to quarter of circumference of circular track**.”

For simplicity, I let $O$ be the center of the circle whose radius is $10$ units, $P$ the starting point, $Q$ is at a quarter of the circle (counting from the anti-clockwise direction), and $R$ is at a distance of $5\pi$ from $P$.

[image]

Therefore, the meeting point is NOT $Q$ but $R$ where $PR =$ minor arc $(PQ) = \frac {2 \pi (10)}{4} = 5\pi$

The angles shown are calculate-able (but I let the machine do the job), such that $\angle POR = 103.44^0$ and reflex $\angle POR = 256.56^0$.

Thus, $\frac {Speed_A}{Speed_C} = \frac {256.56}{103.44} = \frac {5}{2}$ approximately

If I am right, the OP's suggestion must be wrong. Then, if I have to choose one option, I think (b) is the most unlikely "cannot be".

Also, $S$ could be a meeting point too but cannot satisfy the “Speed_A > Speed_C” requirement.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm sorry, for a second I thought it was reviewing test.

Comment: Since the problem does not offer the option "5:2" for the ratio of speeds, and since at least one solution must be correct, I think that you overinterpret what to me looks like a detail of the formulation (though I understand your point of view very well).

Comment: @AlexM. That is why I mentioned in the very beginning that this question should not ask for "what is the 'cannot be'".